# jQuery Cycle Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: php, jquery, syntax-error, cycle

I'm using jQuery cycle to create a few galleries and everything is great, locally. However on the sever I get these two error messages:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery-cycle.js:1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle

Including jQuery and Cycle:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My jQuery Cycle function:

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#mini-gallery').cycle({
          speed: 800,
          timeout: '6500',
          pause: 'true',
          cleartypeNoBg: 'false',
          containerResize:0,
          slideExpr: '.testimonial-mini-item'       
        });
       });
     </script>
```

Why am I getting these error messages on the live server?

**UPDATE**

I've changed the way I load the Cycle plugin to this:

```
   <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Now the plugin works great. Any ideas why this works now? Would this have anything to do with the fact that my I'm using a server IP address and not a domain?

Comment: Check your network (Firebug, or the thing provided by webkit, if you're using chrome for example) to see if you actually download the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check to make sure your `jquery-cycle.js` file doesn't have a missing bracket or something in there that causes the page to fail while loading it.

Comment: I don't think there is an error, I downloaded the plugin straight from the site. There is no error on localhost.

Comment: In that case, I'm not really sure, sorry.  I usually find this error when the parser is expecting a closing bracket somewhere and doesn't find it.  I would make sure it isn't missing maybe elsewhere in your code.  Be sure to check the PHP code, it may be that a PHP condition causes your JS code to break when it is on your site but not when it is local.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the way I load the Cycle plugin to this:

```
 <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Now the plugin works great. Any ideas why this works now? Would this have anything to do with the fact that my I'm using a server IP address and not a domain?